# Excel auto number rows for each record

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set that has multiple records (rows) for each individual.  Is there a way to automatically number the records for each individual?  I want a column that counts the number of rows for each person - without me having to go through and manually number them.

For instance I want the output to look like this (where Person is the original data and Count is filled in by this formula):

| Count | Person |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | P1 |
| 2 | P1 |
| 3 | P1 |
| 1 | P2 |
| 1 | P3 |
| 2 | P3 |
| 1 | P4 |
| 2 | P4 |
| 3 | P4 |
| 4 | P4 |
| 5 | P5 |

[image: example]

Comment: a simple countif with dynamic range will do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use COUNTIF with Dynamic range reference:

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B2,B2)
```

[image]